# How to dynamically update references in an OSGi component?

Tags: osgi, apache-felix

I have an OSGi component `MyComponent` .

This component has reference to a service `MyService`. Now `MyService` has a couple of implementations `MyServiceImpl1` and `MyServiceImpl2`. `MyComponent` also has property `MyProperty`.

Now what I want is that whenever `MyProperty` is 1, `MyComponent.MyService` binds to `MyServiceImpl1`. And if I change `MyProperty` to 2, `MyComponent.MyService` dynamically updates the `MyService` binding  to `MyServiceImpl2.

How do I acheive this? For reference, I am using Apache Felix container and would prefer to avoid lower level OSGi apis.

Answer (score 8):

The easiest way to configure dependencies is with the '.target' property. This requires that the implementations register with an identifying property, lets say `impl=1`. and `impl=2`.

```
@Component(property="impl=1")
public class MyServiceImpl1 implements MyService {
}
@Component(property="impl=2")
public class MyServiceImpl2 implements MyService {
}
```

The component then could look like:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {
    @Reference(target="(impl=1)")
    volatile MyService myService;
}
```

In this case you won't be able to use 1 or 2 as flag but you would have to modify the configuration property for `MyComponent` with the name `myService.target` with another filter. (This is shown with OSGi standardized annotations.)

If you insist on a property that is 1 or 2 (let's call it `select`) for `MyComponent` then it is more elaborate. First we have the problem of being satisfied. Should MyComponent be satisfied when it needs according to the select property impl 1 but only 2 is available? If that is ok then the following much more complicated solution should work

```
@Designate( ocd=Config.class )
@Component( property = "select=1" )
public class MyComponent {
      static Class<?> types [] = {
          MyServiceImpl1.class,
          MyServiceImpl2.class,
      };
      @interface Config {
          int select() default 1;
      }

      @Reference(target="(|(impl=1)(impl=2))")
      volatile List<MyService> candidates;

      volatile MyService selected;

      @Activate
      @Modify
      void changed( Config config ) {
          Class<?> type = types[config.select()];
          Optional<MyService> service = candidates.
              stream().
              filter( type::isInstance ).
              findFirst();
          this.service = service.isPresent() ? service.get() : null;
      }
}
```

As you can see it is generally a bad idea for a component to start to handle its own dependencies. I am therefore curious to your real world scenario.

I find it always very awkward and hard to maintain designs where components are picky about who they reference. It is sometimes inevitable but in general solutions where `MyServiceImpl2` and `MyServiceImpl1` decide to register or not based on some condition reflect reality better.

So the big question I have what does the 1 or 2 property reflect in the real world? Can this not be modeled as a service dependency?

(disclaimer: code not tested and no error handling in it)

Comment: Thanks Peter Kriens for a very insightful answer as always! Let me explain my use case. `MyComponent` basically is a token fetcher which talks to an external REST service to fetch a token. Now there are several variants of this REST service. The `MyServiceImpl`s are basically request mappers corresponding to different variants of the REST service.  I need to provide a mechanism to have `MyComponent` choose the appropriate service impl.

Comment: The question is what the criterium is? Who sets the 0 or 1?

Comment: This is typically set by the system administrator who knows the REST service variant being used and configures the system appropriately. Additionally, `MyComponent` can potentially have multiple instances because of being a configuration factory. In such a scenario, each `MyComponent` instance will use the appropriate service implementation depending on its individual configuration.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming implementation of `MyService` can be queried to report its type (e.g. below):

```
public interface MyService {
    public static final String TYPE = "myservice.type";
}
```

If so, for a Declarative Service OSGi component on Apache Felix, here's an approach:

- keep `MyService` reference in `MyComponent` with

  - `Dynamic` Reference Policy (`policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC`)
  - `1..n` cardinality (`cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE`)
- install `bind/unbind` methods for `MyService` reference in `MyComponent`
- install a `Modified` method in `MyComponent`

`bind/unbind` methods of `MyComponent` will called as and when `MyService` implementations are instantiated by Felix SCR. You would want to maintain a map of available implementations.

`Modified` method will be called whenever there's a configuration-update-event for `MyComponent`. In this method, based on the updated Component Configuration Property, appropriate method can be selected for further processing.

This is how the component would look like when using [Felix SCR annotations](http://felix.apache.org/documentation/subprojects/apache-felix-maven-scr-plugin/scr-annotations.html).

```
@Component (metatype = true, immediate = true)
@Service (value = MyComponent.class)
public class MyComponent {
    @Property(name = "impl.selector", value = "impl_1")
    private String implSelector = "impl_1";

    @Reference(
        referenceInterface = MyService.class,
        policy = ReferencePolicy.DYNAMIC,
        cardinality = ReferenceCardinality.MANDATORY_MULTIPLE,
        strategy = ReferenceStrategy.EVENT,
        bind = "bindService",
        unbind = "unbindService"
    )

    private Map<String, MyService> availableMyServiceImpls = new HashMap<String, MyService>();
    private MyService service = null;

    @Activate
    public void activate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        service = availableMyServiceImpls.get(implSelector);
    }

    @Deactivate
    public void deactivate(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        availableMyServiceImpls.clear();
    }

    public void bindService(MyService serviceRef, Map<?,?> refProperties) {
        String serviceImplName = (String) refProperties.get(MyService.NAME_PROPERTY);
        availableMyServiceImpls.put(serviceImplName, serviceRef);
    }

    public void unbindService(MyService serviceRef, Map<?,?> refProperties) {
        String serviceImplName = (String) refProperties.get(MyService.NAME_PROPERTY);
        availableMyServiceImpls.remove(serviceImplName);
    }

    @Modified
    public void modified(ComponentContext componentContext) {
        Dictionary<String, Object> componentProps = componentContext.getProperties();
        implSelector = PropertiesUtil.toString(componentProps.get("impl.selector"), "");
        service = availableMyServiceImpls.get(implSelector);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is a good approach if the property is changed through configuration, but if it is a method calling a ``setProperty`` method ? You can always call ``modified`` in the ``setProperty`` method, seems a little bit odd but it should work.

Comment: Not sure I follow entirely, @AlexandreCartapanis.

Upon updating the `property` of `MyComponent` above via [Felix's `ConfigurationAdmin` interface](http://felix.apache.org/apidocs/configadmin/1.2.4/org/osgi/service/cm/ConfigurationAdmin.html), viz.

    `Configuration config = configAdmin.getConfiguration(COMPONENT_PID)`
    `config.update(new Hashtable<String, Object>() {{put("impl.selector", "impl_4");}});`

the method annotated as `@Modified` was called.

Can you please help me understand the `setProperty` scenario you allude to?

Comment: If you don't update the ``property`` via Felix ConfigurationAdmin but directly via code (a ``property = XXX`` or a ``setProperty(XXX)`` the method annotated with ``@Modified`` will not be called.

Comment: `public void bindService(MyService serviceRef, Map<?,?> refProperties) ` The 2nd parameter is not documented anywhere, but does work!

Answer (score 1):

First, you must publish your implementations with different filter, to be able to get one or other through filtering.
Then you can change the ServiceReference whenever the property change using [bundleContext.getServiceReferences()](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r4v43/core/org/osgi/framework/BundleContext.html#getServiceReferences(java.lang.Class,%20java.lang.String)).

The technical detail depends on the framework you are using (DS, iPojo, none, ...).

Comment: Thanks Alexandre. I am using Apache Felix framework. I have updated the question with this information.

Comment: Apache Felix is an OSGi framework implementation, but how do you publish your component ? Using an Activator and registerService method, through annotation, ... ?

Comment: Btw, i don't think this is possible without the use of "low-level" API

Comment: The component is published using org.apache.felix.scr.annotations.Component

Comment: First, you better switch to the standard OSGi annotations